# VFX for Unity sci-fi game

Tags: unity, special-effects

Can someone please give me any tips/ guides on how to create hologram, disintegration & freeze effects in Unity game?
I have a sci-fi shooter game in mind, and I would like to incorporate the above mentioned effects in it.

I would like to achieve something like these:

- Holographic effect - [1](http://youtube.com/watch?v=6yEH8XYnqZY),  [2](http://youtube.com/watch?v=NlUtC_NJENQ)
- Disintegration effect - [1](http://youtube.com/watch?v=eZQ_tEUDZZQ)
- Freezing effect - [1](http://youtube.com/watch?v=7qr5oiNn0c4)

And I would prefer to achieve these without using a premium plugin. Budget issues.

Comment: Looks mostly like shader/material effects. What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: Actually, I don't know how to proceed. I don't have much knowledge about shaders. Will I have to create my own custom ones for such a project? Something tells me that the shaders this requires will be pretty complex, won't they?

Answer (score 1):

That disintegration effect is clearly some complex shader work, and the hologram shader on 3D models from your first link may be tricky too, but everything else is easily done with a cubemap and/or additive blending. For the computer monitors, that's just a standard texture in a material with additive blending. For the freeze effect, that can be done with a [cubemap](http://virtualautonomy.com/blog/index.php/2009/08/31/tutorial-2-an-introduction-to-shaders-in?page=5), and for that second hologram model you could do a cubemap AND additive blending.